# How to get axes labels with PlotTheme->"Scientific"?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I'm liking the new plot themes in Mathematica 10, but finding that I can't override the options it sets. For example,

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

returns the right plot but without the axis label. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The theme generates a framed plot. You need to use `FrameLabel`,e.g.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> {Style[x, 30], Style[y, 30]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Comment: You took the time to style your labels. +1 :-)

Answer (score 9):

`"Scientific"` is a framed plot style therefore you need [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameLabel.html):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, FrameLabel -> {x}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Comment: I was to slow...alas